# Issue in two dependent drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

I have database named **courses**

The tables in the database are **countries** and **universities**

The table **countries** contains to fields

**id** ---> as primary key

**countries** ----> as unique key

The table **universities** contains to fields

**universities** ---> as unique key

**id** ----> as foreign key

I am trying to display field **countries** of table **countries** in drop downlist.

and trying to do the same for table **universities**.

My code has no error but it is now showing me send drop down list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<?php
//=======================================================================
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "courses";
//========================================================================
//========================================================================
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//========================================================================
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//========================================================================

$sql = "SELECT id, countries FROM countries";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<select>";

            echo "<option value= ".$row["id"]."> ". $row["countries"]." </option>";

        echo "</select>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

//=============================================================================

    $sql1 = "SELECT universities FROM universities where id = ' ".$row["id"]." '";

    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);


    if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row1 = $result1 -> fetch_assoc()) {



        echo "<select>";

                echo "<option value= > ". $row1["universities"]." </option>";

        echo "</select>";
    }
    }
//======================================================================================

    $conn->close();
//=======================================================================================
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code?  Add it to your question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achive? Send what would you like to have as output from your code

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is already close on above and you are fetching row['id '] below how will it fetch that.

you can verify it by

$sql1 = "SELECT universities FROM universities universities join countries countries on universities.id=countries.id";
 $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);

var_dump($result1); to show actually you are getting value or not.

Answer (score 0):

**$row["id"]** this value will not come outside of the loop.Try the following code,

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT universities FROM universities a join countries b on a.id=b.id";
 $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
```